# Coding a getline() implementation - Valgrind errors

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, getline

I have to recode an implementation of the `getline()` function, but using the file descriptor of the file and not a `FILE *`. I am only allowed to use `malloc()` and `free()`, along with 5 functions being 25 lines long at most.
I think I've done correctly the project although I am a beginner in C and my code isn't probably good.

When I run it, it works fine, but valgrind shows that I `definetely lost x bytes`, x depending of the file length and the READ_SIZE (macro defined in the header).

According to valgrind's `--leak-check=full`, I have a memory leak in the `str_realloc_cat` function, when I malloc `dest`. I tried but couldn't find where should I free / do something else?

Here below is my code:

```
char *get_next_line(const int fd)
{
  static char   *remaining = "";
  char          *buffer;
  ssize_t       cread;
  size_t       i;

  i = 0;
  if (remaining == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  if ((buffer = malloc(SOF(char) * READ_SIZE + 1)) == NULL ||
      (cread = read(fd, buffer, READ_SIZE)) < 0)
        return (NULL);
  buffer[cread] = 0;
  remaining = str_realloc_cat(remaining, buffer);
  while (remaining[i])
    {
      if (remaining[i] == 10)
        {
          remaining[i] = 0;
          buffer = str_create_cpy(remaining);
          remaining = remaining + i + 1;
          return (buffer);
        }
      i++;
    }
  return (check_eof(fd, buffer, remaining, cread));
}

char *str_realloc_cat(char *rem, char *buf)
{
  size_t i;
  size_t dest_i;
  char   *dest;

  i = (dest_i = 0);
  if ((dest = malloc(SOF(char) * (str_len(rem) + str_len(buf) + 1))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  while (rem[i])
    {
      dest[dest_i] = rem[i];
      dest_i++;
      i++;
    }
  i = 0;
  while (buf[i])
    {
      dest[dest_i] = buf[i];
      dest_i++;
      i++;
    }
  dest[dest_i] = 0;
  free(buf);
  return (dest);
}

char    *check_eof(const int fd, char *buffer, char *remaining, ssize_t cread)
{
  if (cread == 0)
    return (NULL);
  if (cread < READ_SIZE)
    {
      buffer = remaining;
      remaining = NULL;
      return (buffer);
    }
  return (get_next_line(fd));
}

char *str_create_cpy(const char *src)
{
  char *dest;
  size_t i;

  i = 0;
  if ((dest = malloc(sizeof(char) * str_len(src) + 1)) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  while (src[i])
    {
      dest[i] = src[i];
      i++;
    }
  dest[i] = 0;
  return (dest);
}

int str_len(const char *str)
{
  size_t i;

  i = 0;
  while (str[i])
    i++;
  return (i);
}
```

And a main functon if you would like to test:

```
#define SOF(x) sizeof(x) // Why in the comments

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  int  fd;
  char *s;

  UNUSED(ac);
  if (!av[1])
    return 1;
  fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
  while ((s = get_next_line(fd)))
    {
      printf("%s\n", s);
      free(s);
    }
  close(fd);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, don't pollute your code with it.

Comment: Using `#define SOF(x) sizeof(x)` — not shown but inferred — seems a tad pointless.  It saves 3 characters of typing per call, at the cost of confusion.  Not a good trade-off.

Comment: Hi, thanks for both your comments. I know `sizeof(char)` is always 1, but I thought it was a good practice so you make sure to never forget it, and don't forget it if somehow a char is more than 1 byte on another system (very unlikely though). Also, SOF is indeed a define of sizeof. That is ugly, but I have to do only 80 characters per line and 25 lines per function so it was kinda for me the only way without being bothered structuring my whole code again.

Comment: "somehow a char is more than 1 byte on another system (very unlikely though)" The only way this could happen is if C compiler is *not* standard-compliant. `sizeof(char)` is 1 according to C standard, it is never system-dependent.

Comment: `foo *bar = malloc(size * sizeof *bar);` is a better practice for structure. But in your case you manipulate bytes so `char *str = malloc(size + 1)` is much better.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! You are right - just thought it would be a good practice. I guess I won't do it again for `char`.

Comment: @Schwern Damn was tired for the if (!av[1]), I already knew it, sorry 'bout that. I wrote that main quickly just to demonstrate my function, hence the multiple mistakes I made.

Comment: `if( !av[1] )` is the incorrect way to check if there is no arguments. While the `av` array is null terminated, it's only guaranteed that `av[ac]` will be null. It is possible for `ac` to be 0 in certain environments. Instead, use `if( ac < 2 )`. I'd also suggest using the conventional `argv` and `argc` for "argument vector" and "argument count". Finally ***never*** use braceless conditions and loop, you're just asking for a very hard to find bug. If you want to save vertical whitespace, switch to 1TBS or [Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_Stroustrup).

Comment: @Greg01re I was a bit wrong and updated my comment. `av` ***is*** null terminated, I never realized that, but it is possible to have *no* arguments (the name of the program is not always available) so `ac == 0` and `av[0] == '\0'` in accordance with the C spec, but `av[1]` will be garbage.

Comment: Trivia — use `int i = 0;` and save yourself a line.  Not entirely trivia — you have `if (remaining[i] == 10)` but should have `if (remaining[i] == '\n')`.

Comment: When you say coding a `getline()` function, you mean some sort of generic 'read a line' rather than mimic POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) except use a file descriptor instead of a file stream as the source? One big difference between file descriptors and file streams is that you don't have buffering on descriptors, yet you don't really want to read one character at a time (it's slow), yet you can only afford to read more if the descriptor is connected to a disk file — not to a terminal or pipe, for example. What do you do about nulls?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not allowed to assign a value to a variable when declaring it (unless it is a `static`).

It is indeed a 'read a line from this file descriptor', but I thought using that as title - people would understand easier. Also I tried reading with 1, it's not *that* slow. About nulls?

Comment: That rule is stupid.  Really *stupid*.  Really, really **stupid**.  It is really, really, really ***bad*** as training for coding C in the non-academic world; it is pretty damn stupid for coding in the academic world too, at least when people want to make any pretense at producing workmanlike, more or less professional code. … Yes, maybe I haven't made it clear yet. …  The rule that says "do not initialize variables when you declare them" is very, very counter-productive.  You must be allowed to initalize arrays.  And frankly, you should initialize most variables as you declare them.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with you... :(

Comment: Null bytes.  POSIX `getline()` returns the number of characters read and handles buffer management through two arguments — `char **bufptr, size_t *buflen`.  This allows it to read past null bytes (`'\0'`), and the calling code to know how much data was read.  You have only a single return value, and that's a `char *`.  You presumably indicate EOF (with no data read) and error by returning NULL, and otherwise a string.  But that means you can't tell how long the data was, and a null byte would screw things up.  This is a problem with `fgets()` too, so you're in good company.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Epitech has some stupid norm to force student to split their function. The rule that you can't initialize your variable is very stupid, that lead to wrong practice. I'm fighting to break this rule. Epitech want this because student are not allowed to create function with more than 25 lines and 80 characters. If you can't initialize a variable you are force to have at least 2 lines by variable declaration and affectation... Worst you **can** **only** declare variable in the beginning of the function, remember 1989? Welcome at Epitech.

Comment: Well, you guessed right :)
Oh, and it's three lines actually since you need to have a line break between variables declarations and initialization.

Comment: Please refrain from vandalizing your post and thus destroying the answerers work. Thank you.

Comment: As I noted I was ASKED to delete this. I would appreciate if a moderator can do it. Else I'll just be "vandalizing" my posts...

Comment: That you were asked to delete this is YOUR problem. Do not vandalize your post. Once you've posted a question and it's been answered, [it doesn't belong just to you, it belongs to everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: If you have **valid and strong reasons** for deleting the question flag your question for *In need of a moderator intervention* and explain in your reasons. "I was asked" is not a reason. As explained in a comment above, this post now belongs to everyone.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is bad:

1. You keep the buffer in a allocate memory
2. You don't use a structure to regroup your variable
3. You use magic number `remaining[i] == 10`
4. You use recursive you can stack overflow `return get_next_line(fd)`. Never mind, I didn't read well you have a tail recursive, just be sure to have the optimization on your compile for it.
5. You have Spaghetti code.
6. etc.

You should rewrite your whole function with a better logic first use this structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define GNL_SIZE 4096

struct gnl_context {
  char buffer[GNL_SIZE];
  size_t i;
  size_t read;
};

char *get_next_line_r(int fd, struct gnl_context *gnl_context);
char *get_next_line(int fd);

static char *read_buffer(struct gnl_context *gnl_context, char *str,
                         size_t *size) {
  size_t i = gnl_context->i;
  while (i < gnl_context->read && gnl_context->buffer[i] != '\n') {
    i++;
  }
  size_t j = i - gnl_context->i;

  char *ret = realloc(str, *size + j + 1);
  if (ret == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  memcpy(ret + *size, gnl_context->buffer + gnl_context->i, j);
  *size += j;
  ret[*size] = '\0';
  gnl_context->i = i;

  return ret;
}

char *get_next_line_r(int fd, struct gnl_context *gnl_context) {
  char *str = NULL;
  size_t size = 0;
loop:
  if (gnl_context->i == gnl_context->read) {
    ssize_t ret = read(fd, gnl_context->buffer, GNL_SIZE);
    if (ret <= 0) {
      return str;
    }
    gnl_context->read = (size_t)ret;
    gnl_context->i = 0;
  }

  char *tmp = read_buffer(gnl_context, str, &size);
  if (tmp == NULL) {
    return str;
  }
  if (gnl_context->i != gnl_context->read) {
    gnl_context->i++;
    return tmp;
  }
  str = tmp;
  goto loop;
}

char *get_next_line(int fd) {
  static struct gnl_context gnl_context;
  return get_next_line_r(fd, &gnl_context);
}

int main(void) {
  char *str;
  while ((str = get_next_line(0)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well tbh I really appreciate the effort and criticism you've put in there, but I was more concerned about fixing my own algorithm, although by the quick look I took to yours, yours is clearly better. I've been coding in C for a little less than 3 months so I guess I still have a lot to learn. I really appreciate it though, and will take a deeper look tomorrow or after I'm done with this project to understand a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I am concerned about this line:

```
remaining = remaining + i + 1;
```

`remaining` is a pointer to the allocated buffer. On this line, you destroy it, which means that you cannot `free()` it anymore.

Comment: Isn't that the only way to move my pointer? I can not really afford a function that would copy everything starting `i + 1` before.

Comment: @Greg01re The problem with that technique is then the memory allocated for `remaining` cannot be freed. You need to hold onto the original pointer in order to free it.

Comment: Well then I guess I'm stuck with leftover memory that can not be free'd?

Comment: @Greg01re Since you are concerned with memory leaks and valgrind barking at you, you should not leave loose ends.

Comment: I indeed am, however it took me quite some time to do that and I shall have it done for in ~20 hours, and afaik they don't check the memory leaks. Considering that, I don't feel like going all over the work again - which I think is understandable. I would've never thought it came from this but it is now quite obvious.

Comment: Just an idea I had, couldn't I increase `remaining`as I already do, but keep tracks of how much I increased it inside a `static` variable so I can free it the last time my function will be called? (when I return `NULL`)?

Comment: @Greg01re This may be a good solution. And feel free to upvote the answer :)

Comment: Will try that and feedback here - if it works, I will obviously mark as solved. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Greg01re Have a look at how [the real `getline` works](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline). Rather than use static memory, it takes a `char **line` for the line output and a `size_t *line_capacity` to record how much memory was allocated. They usually start as `char *line = NULL; size_t line_capacity = 0`. Then `getline` allocates memory for `*line` and notes how much in `*line_capacity`. The same `line` and `line_capacity` get passed back into `getline` for each line, so `line` gets reused or grows as necessary.

Comment: @DYZ Since I realloc it through the `str_realloc_cat` function, it doesn't seems very possible to do what I thought. Maybe I'm wrong, going to sleep to see if tomorrow will be  better for me :D.

@Schwern It's a bit late for me now to do that, though I'll take a look for extra learning purposes.