# Malloc error: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

I've been trying to fix this for 2 days now. I really don't understand what is going on.

I wrote a function to read from a file line per line. It's called **get_next_line()**. This is a project for school, I'm only allowed to use my own C library and **read()**, **malloc()** and **free()**.

[Here is a link to the full GitHub repo](https://github.com/pdeguing/get_next_line), including the instructions. I can only submit **get_next_line.c** and **get_next_line.h** at the end.

Basically, my program seems to run fine if don't handle memory leaks. When I start fixing leaks by using my **ft_strdel()** function, my program still runs fine for most test cases.

```
void    ft_strdel(char **as)
{
    if (!as || !*as)
        return ;
    free(*as);
    *as = 0;
}
```

Yet, if I pass it through the advanced unit test we have at school, I have different errors. They seem to appear randomly sometimes as I can pass 3 times in a row and get a malloc error the 4th time.

The current version seems to handle all memory leaks. Thus, I have this error from the filechecker:

> get_next_line_tests(43165,0x7fff9e83d340) malloc: ***
>   error for object 0x7fe0e3403748: incorrect checksum for freed object -
>   object was probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

---

### Here is the full function:

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

static t_list   *get_current_node(const int fd, t_list **line_list)
{
    t_list      *tmp;

    tmp = *line_list;
    while (tmp)
    {
        if ((int)tmp->content_size == fd)
            return (tmp);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return (NULL);
}

static t_list   *create_new_node(int fd, t_list **line_list)
{
    t_list  *new;

    new = ft_lstnew("\0", fd);
    ft_lstadd(line_list, new);
    return (new);
}

char            *read_until_newline(int fd)
{
    char    buf[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
    char    *tmp;
    char    *stack;
    int     ret;

    if (read(fd, buf, 0) < 0)
        return (NULL);
    stack = ft_strnew(1);
    if (!stack)
        return (NULL);
    while ((ret = read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        tmp = ft_strjoin(stack, buf);
        ft_strdel(&stack);
        stack = tmp;
        if (ft_strchr(buf, '\n'))
            break;
    }
    return (stack);
}

int             get_index_newline(char *str)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] && str[i] != '\n')
        i++;
    return (i);
}

int     get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    static t_list   *line_list;
    t_list          *current;
    char            *buffer;
    char            *tmp;
    int             index_newline;

    if (fd < 0 || line == NULL)
        return (-1);
    current = get_current_node(fd, &line_list);
    if (!current)
        current = create_new_node(fd, &line_list);
    if (!ft_strchr(current->content, '\n'))
        buffer = read_until_newline(fd);
    else
        buffer = ft_strnew(1);
    if (!buffer)
        return (-1);
    if (!ft_strlen(buffer) && !ft_strlen(current->content))
        return (0);
    tmp = current->content;
    current->content = ft_strjoin(tmp, buffer);
    if (tmp)
        ft_strdel(&tmp);
    if (buffer)
        ft_strdel(&buffer);
    index_newline = get_index_newline(current->content);
    *line = ft_strsub(current->content, 0, index_newline);
    tmp = current->content;
    current->content = ft_strsub(tmp, index_newline + 1, ft_strlen(tmp) - index_newline - 1);
    if (tmp)
        ft_strdel(&tmp);
    return (1);
}
```

Feel free to comment on any beginner error I could be doing in my code. Please note however that I have to follow a certain norm, that explain my variable declarations and initializations. I cannot use *for* loops. And have many restrictions like those.

Protecting my **ft_strdel()** calls with *if* statements was my last attent at solving the issue, obviously it failed and it's useless.

EDIT:

I handle multiple *fd* by using a *static linked list*. Each node contains a string with the last read buffer (whatever is left from the reading after substracting the most recently read line). And each node contains an int to store the *fd* it was read from. This way, I loop through the list until I find the corresponding *fd* to check for preexisting reading. If no node is returned, it means I have nothing stored for the specific fd so I'll just create a new node.

I hope you have answers! I'm not a regular user on Stack Overflow, I did my best to format my post and be specific. Tell me if I need to edit something.

And thanks for your help!

Comment: If your platform supports [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), run to download it and start using it — it will tell you remarkably precisely where you're going wrong, especially if you compile and link with the `-g` (debug information) flag.

Comment: In the function which starts `int     get_next_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    static t_list   *line_list;`, how does your code handle two different file descriptors being used to read two different files in parallel?  The `static t_list *line_list;` suggests that it won't handle that case very well.  It might be easier to understand if you showed your declarations — I know you gave a link, but we shouldn't need to go off-site to see relevant information.  Please (re)read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: the first problem is that your way have few design problem, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656292/7076153), you have the same problems.

Comment: Compiling with `-fsanitize=address` is another way to detetct memory issues.

Comment: `read(fd, buf, 0)` Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: I do this to check the validity of the file to read, just to be sure read() wont return (-1)